# Declare dependency to war file in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, war

Based on the gradle [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies), to define external jars means adding to `build.gradle` the following snippet (considering you have {project_root}/libs/foo.jar) in place:

```
dependencies {
  runtime files('libs/foo.jar')
}
```

However, using the same dependency declaration for `*.war` files doesn't  work. Is this even possible? The project I'm trying to depend on builds to a war file.

Comment: It seems that you're trying to misuse war file. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to write a YAML schema interpreter and would like to reuse utility classes from [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck) project.

Comment: From which part exactly? Which class would you like to use?

Comment: This [codec](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/blob/development/rundeckapp/grails-app/utils/rundeck/codecs/JobsYAMLCodec.groovy). Particularly interested in using `decode` method to parse raw YAMLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since war layout is different from jar file standard layout, it's not possible to declare war a dependency file to a java project. Possible ideas:

1. Clone the project and define it as a dependency (very stupid idea, I'm ashamed that I suggest sth like that)
2. Contact the author and ask him/her if you can just copy the class you need to use. If you can copy the class along with the credits.
3. Contact the author and ask him/her if it does make sense to make the codec open source (I know it is right now) and release it as a standalone jar library (maybe along with other classes used in the project).