# Can resolve dependency via artifactory using maven but not using gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory

I am having a problem resolving a dependency via artifactory using gradle. But I can resolve that dependency using maven, so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

The maven build file is:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>geoserver</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <type>war</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <name>libs-releases</name>
    <url>http://<artifactory-host>/artifactory/libs-releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I can confirm that maven will resolve the dependency:

```
$ mvn dependency:resolve
Downloading: http://<artifactory-host>/artifactory/libs-releases/org/geoserver/geoserver/2.5.1/geoserver-2.5.1.pom
Downloading: http://<artifactory-host>/artifactory/libs-releases/org/geoserver/web/2.5.1/web-2.5.1.pom
Downloading: http://<artifactory-host>/artifactory/libs-releases/org/geoserver/geoserver/2.5.1/geoserver-2.5.1.war
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    org.geoserver:geoserver:war:2.5.1:compile
```

My gradle build script is:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'http://<artifactory-host>/artifactory/libs-releases' }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.geoserver:geoserver:2.5.1@war'
}
```

But gradle will not resolve the dependency:

```
$ gradle dependencies
:dependencies

compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- org.geoserver:geoserver:2.5.1 FAILED
```

I've cleaned out the local repository and caches, to ensure that dependencies are resolved. If I turn on debug output I can see that there are HTTP requests for the POM file, but there are no HTTP requests for the WAR file.

```
[DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Sending request: HEAD /artifactory/libs-releases/org/geoserver/geoserver/2.5.1/geoserver-2.5.1.pom HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I can download both the POM and the WAR file directly, so it's not a problem with the artifacts not existing, or proxy issues, or authentication issues:

```
$ wget http://<artifactory-host>/artifactory/libs-releases/org/geoserver/geoserver/2.5.1/geoserver-2.5.1.pom
`geoserver-2.5.1.pom' saved [32283/32283]

$ wget http://<artifactory-host>/artifactory/libs-releases/org/geoserver/geoserver/2.5.1/geoserver-2.5.1.war
`geoserver-2.5.1.war' saved [60164745/60164745]
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong here. It's probably something simple?

**edit #1** I added a dependency on a JAR file in artifactory, which resolved without error. And then I added a dependency on another WAR file in artifactory, which also resolved without error. But for some reason the original geoserver WAR dependency resolves when using maven, but not when using gradle.

**edit #2** I see the following warning when using the maven build:

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.geoserver:geoserver:war:2.5.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 2 problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.geoserver:geoserver:2.5.1
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM org.geoserver:geoserver:2.5.1, must be "pom" but is "war" @ 
[FATAL] The parents form a cycle: org.geoserver:geoserver:2.5.1 -> org.geoserver:web:2.5.1 -> org.geoserver:geoserver:2.5.1 @
```

Looking at the geoserver 2.5.1 soure code:

- `org.geoserver:geoserver` (WAR) has parent `org.geoserver:web` (POM)
- `org.geoserver:web` (POM) has parent `org.geoserver:geoserver` (WAR)

So there is a cyclic dependency, and the parent of `org.geoserver:web` has a non-POM packaging.

But maven goes on to download the WAR file despite this 'fatal' error:

```
Downloaded: http://<artifactory-host>/artifactory/libs-releases/org/geoserver/geoserver/2.5.1/geoserver-2.5.1.war (58755 KB at 8601.2 KB/sec)
```

Maybe gradle is more strict on this problem?

**edit #3** I changed the dependency to exclude transitive dependencies on `org.geoserver:geoserver`:

```
dependencies {
  compile('org.geoserver:geoserver:2.5.1@war') {
    transitive = false
  }
  ...
```

but the dependency still did not resolve when I ran `$ gradle dependencies`.

There is a stack overflow error when I run a task using this dependency:

```
$ gradle bundleArtifacts
:bundleArtifacts
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not resolve org.geoserver:geoserver:2.5.1.
  Required by:
    <my-project>:1.0-SNAPSHOT
> Could not resolve org.geoserver:geoserver:2.5.1.
> Could not parse POM http://<artifactory-host>/artifactory/libs-releases/org/geoserver/geoserver/2.5.1/geoserver-2.5.1.pom
> Could not resolve org.geoserver:web:2.5.1.
> Could not parse POM http://<artifactory-host>/artifactory/libs-releases/org/geoserver/web/2.5.1/web-2.5.1.pom
> Could not resolve org.geoserver:geoserver:2.5.1.
...
```

This shows that gradle does not get to consider the transitive dependencies, because it cannot parse the POM files, because of the cyclic dependency.

I think the only solution here is to create a separate artifact (such as a ZIP file) that contains the `org.geoserver:geoserver:2.5.1` WAR artifact, add a dependency on that ZIP file, and create a task that extracts the contents of that ZIP file to a target directory.

Comment: The [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31177058/declare-dependency-to-war-file-in-gradle) say you cannot add a war as a compile dependency.

Comment: Thanks ... I changed `compile` to `runtime` but still failed to resolve ... see my edits.

Comment: Well I really should have said *cannot add war as a dependency* compile or runtime - atleast that's what the question I linked to says.

Comment: I added a compile dependency on a different WAR artifact (see my edits) and that resolved successfully. I think the problem is that gradle is not as lenient as maven when dealing with POM errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using modified pom files which are causing this issue.
The package type of the original [org.geoserver:geoserver](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/2.5.1/src/pom.xml) module is pom and it has no parent. This is the parent pom for the entire geoserver project and should not be used as a dependency.
The [org.geoserver:web](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/2.5.1/src/web/pom.xml) is also of type pom and serves as the parent for all web related modules.
Looking at the [geoserver Artifactory server](https://repo.boundlessgeo.com), I could not find any artifacts named `geoserver-x.x.x.war`. It seems that someone deployed [web archive](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.8.1/geoserver-2.8.1-war.zip) (war) distribution of geoserver and modified the original pom file of `org.geoserver:geoserver` so it can be resolved.

If you would like to continue resolving this war, I suggest creating a new dedicated .pom file for it which will not conflict with the geoserver one (using a new groupId/artifactId).

Comment: Yeah, looks like the pom file for org.geoserver:geoserver on the local artifactory is different to the one on github. Something underhand is afoot, and I will need to fix it.

Comment: It looks like someone was trying to modify `org.geoserver:web` to be `org.geoserver:geoserver`. Interesting that maven allowed this, while gradle rejected it (although the POM parsing in the presence of cyclic dependencies needs some fixing).